# Storing sensitive user data in Android

Tags: java, android

I apologize in advance if this question is a duplicate. I did some search and didn't find what I was looking for. Suppose I make an Android app that had some sort of virtual currency (for example, coins in games) which can be purchased for real money via PayPal or CreditCard. Does Google offer me a way to store this information somehow or do i need to have a separate database server and keep such data in a separate database that has nothing to do with Google account. My app would not have any custom user accounts or anything of such ..The data stored would be dependant on Google user account.
Thanks.

Comment: How are you planning on distributing the app? If the answer is "the Play Store", then your one-and-only option is Google's [in-app purchasing system](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The google TOS require you to handle every IAP over the play store and the google IAP APIs. To my knowledge, no app has ever been banned from the play store for using PayPal though.

The usual flow for buying in-app-coins is:

- purchase via play store IAP
- save amount of new coins to your own server
- retrieve total amount of coins from your server
- user server calls for adding/removing coins

Alternatively you can save the amount of coins on the device, this will get lost though if the user uninstalls the app or removes the app data.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know it's not allowed. The sole existence of Paypal Android SDK which i stumbled upon gave me a hint such payments are possible, but i guess it's for off-store aps. Thanks.

Comment: I looked that up one or two years ago. At this time, it was not really allowed by the google TOS, but they never took down an app for using another payment method. I'm not sure how the situation is now. But using the google IAP is really easy anyways, so no reason not to use it.